# Detecting a change in timeseries data

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, time-series, real-time

Let's say I have 4 heat sensors on each corner of a square. The more a sensor moves towards a heated object its value increased from a scale of 0 to 1. Lets say I move this square which one sensor (F1) was close towards a heated object towards another heated object on the other side. On the way from one side to the other F1 starts decreases in value while let's say F4 starts increasing. How do I detect this change over a window of iterations? I want the algorithm to tell me that there is a change occurring with F1 and F4, meanwhile F3 could be changing but not significantly.

- Iter 1: **F1 = 0.9** - F2 = 0.4  -   F3 = 0.1  - **F4 = 0.11**
- Iter 2: **F1 = 0.85** - F2 = 0.405 - F3 = 0.1  - **F4 = 0.15**
- Iter 3: **F1 = 0.80** - F2 = 0.41  -  F3 = 0.12 - **F4 = 0.25**

Comment: What about just looking at the derivatives of each sensor and using some appropriate cut-off values?

Comment: This is not my ultimate goal. I am trying to interpolate something else depending on the change between those to values F1, and F4..

Comment: Does that mean you want a _measure of change_ rather than some boolean _"things are changing"_ kind of solution?

Comment: Yes, exactly, this is what I am aiming at...

Answer (score 0):

The problem with trying to boil down multiple measures into one is the inevitable loss of information, and as such there wont be a single measure that works for all cases.

Judging from your comments, I would try something like this:

```
# F*_d is the derivative of the F* sensor
m = e^(-(|F2_d| + |F3_d|))*(1 + |F1_d| + |F2_d|)
```

The thinking is that you want `|F2_d| + |F3_d|` close to 0, and which would make the first term pretty much 1. The result should then be close to `1 + |F1_d| + |F2_d|`. If F2_d and F3_d is too big, the first term will dominate and you should see a small value.

I would play around with different coefficients and/or move some `|.|` around to get what you want.

(Note that `|.|` means the absolute value, that is `abs(.)`)

Comment: What is the name of the method, or algorithm?

Comment: @MasterWizard No named model as far as I know, just a compote of personal reasoning. It likely wont fit correctly with what you actually want as is, which is why I suggested you play with the parameters. It's probably possible to create a better model of the system, but more information about the 'heat function' would likely be needed.

Comment: the heat function is not important at all, Im just modeling the idea after something that everyone would understand, I am more concerned about detecting the change...

Comment: @MasterWizard And the suggested model does not reflect the change?